# Workflow error notification

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow

What is the best practice for handling if a workflow fails? I can see the error that appears in the column but is there an easy way to set up a notification that will immediately email specific people when it fails? I am not looking for specific help on the error. I am looking for a way to be notified when the workflow fails.

This is in reference to sharepoint on premise 2019, with 2013 workflow.

Comment: Hi don't know, you'll be more likely to get an answer to your question if you are more specific and keep it succinct.  Really your questions amounts to 'my workflow failed, how can I test it'.  It might be better to scale your question back to that.  Have you done any research, tried stuff out already?  What permissions do you have?  Are you the Sharepoint Administrator?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I am a front end dev working with a sharepoint site. I know how to solve why the workflow broke. But I want to be notified if it fails again. Do I need to create a flow to check this or are there specific notifications that I can turn on?